# Opt-in to be always pingable to answer questions

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, chat

> Original idea: [List of users with specialities who are willing to be pinged--should we do this?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1153/list-of-users-with-specialities-who-are-willing-to-be-pinged-should-we-do-this)

This is a place where users can opt in to be pinged by other users regardless of their chat status.

### What sort of pings is this for?

Try to keep the ping related to P.SE . Some example uses of this would be to

- Ask a specific user for help on one of your question/answers. Try to wait for the rest of the community, only use this if you have gotten no response.
- Let a specific user know that they might enjoy answering `<question>`
- Let a specific user know about an unanswered question within their specialization
- Notify a user for SE-related miscellaneous stuff.

## Instructions

### If you would like to render yourself pingable

- Post an answer to this question, indicating your specialties (if any). You may also list which types of questions you prefer to answer.
- Other stuff you can do to help: Keep your specialties in your profile text (preferably so that they show up on [your expanded usercard](https://physics.stackexchange.com/privileges/established-user)). Do the same for your chat profile. Also, try to stay  logged in to chat.

### If you would like to ping a user

First, check if that user is on [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/the-coupling). Start typing their username in chat, and if it pops up, then notify them there. It's always preferable to use chat for such notifications. If the user is not on chat, *just comment on their post below with your message*.

Try to delete the comment once you have recieved indication that the user has seen it.

Comment: Strange, when I first tried to edit this adding only the q, a, and chat tags, it said "The moderator tag "featured" must always be present  whereas        when I did add it (I wonder how), it said  that it can only be used by moderators, but still  saved the edit nevertheleass. And yet, seeing the edit history, it was done ages ago by mbq.

Comment: @DImension10AbhimanyuPS That's because the tag hides itself if not removed.

Answer (score 9):

[Frédéric Grosshans](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/373/frederic-grosshans)

Specialities (research level): Quantum information (more specifically, quantum communication, quantum cryptography and quantum entanglement)

Likes to answer: beyond the above, I have an interest in the links between physics and information theory, and I love to give original answer to general physics question, but I do not always have time to do it.

Answer (score 9):

[image: profile for F'x on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites]

Specialities: physical chemistry, thermodynamics, statistical physics of molecular systems

Answer (score 9):

I am more than happy to answer most General Relativity questions.

Answer (score 8):

[profile for EnergyNumbers on Physics.SE http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/339125.png](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/4066/energynumbers) Ping me on human uses of non-food energy:
[building-physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/building-physics) [climate-science](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/climate-science) [electricity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electricity) [photovoltaics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/photovoltaics) [power](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/power)  [renewable-energy](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/renewable-energy)

Answer (score 7):

[Manishearth](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/users/7433)

[enter link description here http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/1212053.png](http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/1212053.png)

Specialities: None.

Likes to answer: Stuff requiring analogies, electromagnetism, basic QM and relativity.

I'm usually on chat anyways, but its better to keep this here.

Answer (score 7):

Specialties: quantum mechanics, quantum field theory, Lie algebras in physics, statistical physics, foundations of physics

@EmilioPisanty: See my profile for availability.

Comment: Arnold, I presume you've seen the edit to this post, but maybe you haven't. You've been back since it was added, but it may still be accurate. Just thought I'd point it out.

Answer (score 5):

**Interests:** [quantum-field-theory](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quantum-field-theory), [general-relativity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/general-relativity), [quantum-mechanics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quantum-mechanics), [string-theory](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string-theory), [mathematical-physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mathematical-physics)

(Of course, I'm open to responding to other inquiries, but these are my dominant interests.)

Comment: This is nice of you, and the answer here should obtain many more upvotes ...!

Comment: @Dilaton: It's my pleasure, I'm always open to being interrupted by a great question on the SE.

Answer (score 4):

[image: profile for Pratik Deoghare on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites]

I have no specialities. But I am interested in (almost) everything.

Answer (score 3):

**Specialties** [general-relativity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/general-relativity), [cosmology](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cosmology), [inflation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/inflation) (actually pretty much all cosmology topics), [rocket-science](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rocket-science) (and/or satellites/space tech), [engineering](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/engineering).

Most importantly, I always try to answer in a fun way at the appropriate level. My students always tell me I make them like physics again (except the physics majors, who obviously already like physics).