# Can I send "private messages'' to a user?

Tags: support

First I am sorry if this question is repeated

Is there a way to send a private message to a user?

Answer (score 5):

There is no private message facility and the team has regularly and robustly turned down all such suggestions.

You can get another user's attention by [tagging them in the comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) (though they need to have participated in the discussion or editing of a post for that to work), and you can (with [sufficient rep](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat-rooms)) open a chat room for holding a conversation. That last suggestion isn't private in the sense that others are excluded but you probably won't have a lot of people poking their noses in.

The mantra is "This is not a social network!".

However, some Physics SE user find this to be insufficiently friendly and have responded with the meta.physics most ["Opt-in to be always pingable to answer questions"](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1159/520) where you are explicitly invited to ping them in order to direct their attention to other posts.

Comment: I didn't realize that tagging was not "system wide". Does that mean that if I would like to call the attention of another user to a particular question, it would not be sufficient to @tag them in a comment to that question - I need to find another answer of theirs and leave the comment / link there? That's a little bit awkward. I feel a need to use my batman signal from time to time... I wondered why I wasn't getting a response.

Comment: @Floris It means exactly that. And there are to only no plans to fix the awkwardness but an understanding that is *should not* be fixed. This is not a social network. But I'll add a note to my answer about a special feature of Physics SE that might be useful.

Comment: that clears it up - thanks.