# About comments to questions relative to others

Tags: discussion

May I ask from someone ,through a comment, who gave an answer to a question relevant to a another question of mine, to check my question and tell me his opinion commenting or if he wishes answering it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no mechanism for contacting users about a post if they have not already participated in that post, and for good reason. This is not meant to be a social network, and there is a real concern that relatively famous users would get so many unsolicited requests for help they would simply leave the site.

That said, if the two questions are really very closely linked, it would be okay to leave a comment like "you might want to have a look at this related question of mine." But don't make a habit of it, and try not to focus on a select few users. The key is to not pester anyone.

Besides, most questions that can be answered can be answered by many users here, and if you always seek out one person in particular, while flattering for that person, can come off as a bit dismissive of everyone else's ability.

There is an exception to the "don't go around asking particular people to solve your problems" rule, and that is our [list of pingable users](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1159/opt-in-to-be-always-pingable-to-answer-questions). If anyone has listed themselves there, they are okay with being notified of questions in their topics of interest. That said, I'm fairly certain very few people utilize that resource.

Comment: I understand and agree with you. I'm not reffering to a particular user but in general to one who has answered a relevant question.